# Three.js : Canvas not taking full height only on production build (just needs a resize)

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, renderer

I have an issue occurring with the production build of my app.

Everything works fine in development. But as soon as I build my app, then uses gh-pages to serve the build folder, this issue occurs :

When the page is loaded, the canvas will only take a fraction of the window's height (see screenshot). For some reason, it also doesn't take the full width, but almost it.

[image: The issue when loading the page]

It will only happen when loading the page, but it's fixed as soon as you resize the window.

Here is a link to the repo : https://github.com/polar0/metaverse

The demo, where you can see the issue : https://polar0.github.io/metaverse/
Just try to resize your browser, and it should be ok again.

The part of the code related to the renderer. I believe it's correctly written, but I'm not sure of anything.
https://github.com/polar0/metaverse/blob/main/src/World/systems/renderer.js

I feel like this problem is occuring only when the app is served from the dist folder. Maybe it comes from gh-pages ?

I couldn't find any related problem, and I really don't know where to look anymore. It's also not convenient for debugging, that the issue only happens with the production build.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It works for me on the live site :)